# boolean value in linesegment constructor

Tags: c#, wpf

MSDN describers [LineSegment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms602523.aspx) `LingSegment( Point p, bool isStroked)` as method/constructor *to initialize a new instance of the LineSegment class that has the specified end Point and Boolean that determines whether this LineSegment is stroked.*

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms602523.aspx

I'm using it when drawing of a line segment is almost complete ... meaning point A is created and now ending point has to be created which makes it but changing the boolean parameter to false or true (isStroked) doesn't make any changes in appearance of line.

What exactly is isStroked parameter?

Answer (score 0):

It determines the [PathSegment.IsStroked](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.pathsegment.isstroked.aspx) property.

> When you switch between stroked and non-stroked PathSegment sections in a PathFigure, it is considered the same as the dashes of a Pen. The DashCap property of the Pen object determines the shape of the ends of stroked PathSegment objects.

So basically, if your LineSegment is part of a larger path, the IsStroked determines if it's a drawn part of a dashed pen, or the non-drawn part.